# rxvt-unicode does not accept Ctrl-F to move the cursor to next letter for Bash and GNU readline and other shells

Tags: bash, readline, urxvt

Am using i3 window manager, rxvt-unicode 9.26, bash 5.1.16, and yash 2.52.

Already on `set -o emacs` mode.

Using `~/.Xresources` file:

```
!! ~/.Xresources

!!
!! rxvt-unicode (urxvt)
!!

URxvt.geometry:             96x32
URxvt.scrollBar_right:      true
URxvt.scrollBar_floating:   true
URxvt.scrollstyle:          plain
URxvt.cursorBlink:          true
URxvt.cursorUnderline:      true
URxvt.pointerBlank:         true
URxvt.visualBell:           false
URxvt.saveLines:            3000
URxvt.fading:               40

URxvt.tabbed.no-tabbedex-keys: true

!! Font list and Spacing
URxvt.font:                 xft:Cica-12
URxvt.letterSpace:          -1
!URxvt.lineSpace:            0

!! Color Scheme and Opacity - gruvbox-dark https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox
URxvt.depth:                32
URxvt.color0:               [90]#282828
URxvt.color1:               [90]#cc241d
URxvt.color2:               [90]#98971a
URxvt.color3:               [90]#d79921
URxvt.color4:               [90]#458588
URxvt.color5:               [90]#b16286
URxvt.color6:               [90]#689d6a
URxvt.color7:               [90]#a89984
URxvt.color8:               [90]#928374
URxvt.color9:               [90]#fb4934
URxvt.color10:              [90]#b8bb26
URxvt.color11:              [90]#fabd2f
URxvt.color12:              [90]#83a598
URxvt.color13:              [90]#d3869b
URxvt.color14:              [90]#8ec07c
URxvt.color15:              [90]#ebdbb2
URxvt.foreground:           [90]#ebdbb2
URxvt.background:           [90]#282828
URxvt.colorIT:              [90]#8ec07c
URxvt.colorBD:              [90]#d5c4a1
URxvt.colorUL:              [90]#83a598
URxvt.scrollColor:          [90]#504945
!URxvt.troughColor:          [90]#3C3836
```

Though C-a, C-e, M-f, M-b and C-b works as in [this documentation from Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Interaction.html) -- keybinds to edit command line; all of which moves the cursor, C-f -- the one to move the cursor to next letter -- does not; what am I missing?

I suspected that it is an issue by urxvt, as ctrl-f may be reserved for a certain shortcut.

---

Now appended these two lines to disable Perl extensions, two of which uses keybinds C-f and C-M-f:

```
URxvt.perl-ext:
URxvt.perl-ext-common:
```

Comment: In `bash`, what do you get when you do `bind -p|grep C-f` ?

Comment: @Philippe `"\C-f": forward-char
"\e\C-f": shell-forward-word
`

Comment: What happens when you type `Ctrl-F` ? Does it work in other terminals like `xterm` ?

Comment: @Philippe Just installed `xterm`. Then I typed the key on C-f to get a new window of xterm. It happened for both rxvt-unicode and xterm (and also uxterm). Happened whatever the program runs, such as interactive shell, running `cat` to input strings from stdin, `vim`ming, etc. When I uninstalled `xterm`, the keybind caused nothing.

Comment: So the problem is not specific to `rxvt-unicode`, right ? Can `i3 window manager` captured Ctrl-F ?

Comment: @Philippe [no](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_default_keybindings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I AM VERY SORRY I was a user of `startx` whose config file is `~/.xinitrc`: it has a line `xbindkeys` whose config file is `~/.xbindkeysrc` who has two lines

```
"xterm"
  c:41 + m:0x4
```

Then I made this to comment, which finally worked.